# Pin Swap for an FMC Connector

Tags: pcb, connector, altium, pcb-fabrication, pins

What determines if you can swap pins on an FMC or not? I can technically swap the pins on a PCB footprint but the datasheets don't show the pin arrangement I'm about to make to make the trace routes connect the Connector pins to the components properly. I'm using Altium Designer and need to make sure the FMC Connector will be able to be manufactured during PCB fabrication process.

**FPGA-Compatible MIPI CSI-2 (Camera Serial Interface) D-PHY adapter board Schematic:**
[image: FPGA-Compatible MIPI CSI-2 (Camera Serial Interface) D-PHY adapter board Schematic]

**Original PCB layout before changing FMC Connector pins and before trace routing:**
[image: Original PCB layout before changing FMC Connector pins and before trace routing]

**Final PCB layout after changing FMC Connector pins and after trace routing:**
[image: Final PCB layout after changing FMC Connector pins and after trace routing]

Comment: Can you provide some context? Schematics? Layout?

Comment: The LPC FMC Mezzanine Connector has 4 columns, each with 40 columns, as shown here: https://fmchub.github.io/appendix/VITA57_FMC_HPC_LPC_SIGNALS_AND_PINOUT.html. On the LPC (Low-Pin Count) FMC Connector, the table specifies columns as H,G,C, and D, with respective signals. For trace route optimization between the FMC Connector pins and other parts of the PCB, I need to swap, for example, D21 and C23 and swap C1 and C2. The pin swapping are required between columns and within a column. Pins are mechanically identical and are specified according to signals. Images are linked above in post ^.

Comment: You can define the specific channel pins in your FPGA design. As for your layout, you don't maintain characteristic impedance, you should route the traces as differential pairs. In Altium assign a _P and _N suffixes to each net.

Comment: For this external adapter board, would the designer have the map out any traces as "differential"? I read through Xilinx standards that the differentials should be regarded for the traces that define CLK and DATA. There are pinouts of the Connectors that configure CLK and DATA signals, so I presume that this adapter board (without the FPGA) would require differential trace routes. Would you agree?

Comment: This is your design, we can't know what your requirements are, however, the net names in the connector give you a hint.